# which core code is responsible for compiling the JavaScript in this plugin

Tags: javascript, plunker

Recently I was going through the [plunker compiler](https://github.com/ggoodman/plunker-run-plugin), I have not used mongodb before, and do not wish to set it up for understanding how the compiler is working. So, I would like to know, how can i setup this project removing the mongodb adapter, with only the core compiling feature, also, can anybody point me to the code that is responsible for compiling the angularjs and other javascript framework codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not used mongodb before, and do not wish to set it up for understanding how the compiler is working.

The Plunker run server does not have a dependency on mongo. When it renders plunks it pulls them from the Plunker API server [defined here](https://github.com/ggoodman/plunker-run-plugin/blob/master/config.example.js#L17).

> can anybody point me to the code that is responsible for compiling the angularjs and other javascript framework codes?

The Plunker run server does not actually compile libraries like Angular and other frameworks. When the Plunker package catalogue adds these frameworks to a Plunk, it injects `<script src="http://.."></script>` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://..">` tags into the `index.html`. Since those bits of code are available at public urls, your browser is pulling them from those locations when you preview your work and the Plunker run server is not involved at all.

As for compilation which happens in other circumstances, as [described in the README](https://github.com/ggoodman/plunker-run-plugin/blob/master/README.md), th

Comment: thanks for the reply, so the function of the run server is to actually to do the explicit conversion (babel, typescript etc to pure javscript) ?

Comment: The function of the run server is three-fold: 1) it accepts previews that it stores temporarily in-memory and serves them when requested (what you interact with in the editor); 2) it lazily-loads saved plunks and serves them as in (1); and 3) it does explicit and implicit compilation for missing files as described in the README.